# SSIS using windows credential in agent job

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I have an SSIS package that inserts some data to Server B Which is in domain B.
But my user is in Domain A and I am running the package in Server A which does not see domain B.

I have added a windows credential to server A and I can connect to Server B with windows authentication also I can run the job in the server using visual studio but when I run the package with a job It says my user does not have access to the server B.

my problem is a little different than SQL proxy I think because I tried it and it did not solve my issue. what I did was I created a credential on my user(in server A) and add it as a proxy to the job and I thought it will run it like I am running it with visual studio (while I am remote on the server) but still, I get the error.

I can't add credentials of server B because the domains are not trusted and It can't see the user.

**Update:**

my friend suggested **"cross domain authenticate"**
which means I create a user with the same name as the Server B Username and also with the same password on Server A and if I run the job with this user it should be able to connect to both servers. It looks promising but did not work on the first try I will investigate it more and update here.

Comment: What are you *actually* asking here? You say what you have isn't working, but you don';t tell us what it is it is doing that fails. The fact that the authentication fails means you're using a login that doesn't have access; change the login that is being used. Where you change that we can't say, as we have no information about what you are, or rather the package, is *really* doing.

Comment: Agent job runs under the Windows login of SQL Server Agent, which won't have access to the Windows Credential that you saved.

Comment: my problem is with SSIS I want to insert data from a server to another server and they are not in the same domain.
the package I developed works fine in visual studio (while I am remote because  I can only see the destination server from my server)
but when I schedule it in a job it does not work it reads the data from my table but returns and error and can't insert to destination

Comment: @Charlieface I know but what's the solution?
the job is running by my user and even with a proxy to run it as my user, it does not work.
my agent has a custom user so if I remote as that user and add to credential does it work? ( I have to get the password from my boss so I want to avoid it as much as possible)

Comment: And what is that error? YOu say you can "see" the server in VS, which implies that the server you are running the package on can't. If so, no credentials are going to change that. If the Server the package is running on can't resolve the address of the remote host, it will never be able to connect. Just like I can 't connect to your PC.

Comment: @Larnu these 2 servers are not on the same domain.
I can't see the other user in creating a proxy
it works with credentials in visual studio
I can run the package manually in the visual studio
i can't run it as a job

Comment: Then it'll be impossible for the server to connect.If the Server the package is running on can't resolve a connection to the remote server, as no path exists, it can't connect. End of Story. You'll need to speak to your network administrator(s) so that they can enable a path between the domains so that a host on one domain can resolve a path to one on the other. It might well be limited to specific host(s), but you'll still need it.

Comment: If a path does exist, then you could use SQL Authentication in your connection manager but until a path is made, you'll get no where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

domain authenticate does work very well.
all I had to do was add that user to SQL-server and then create a proxy.
after that, I set the proxy in the step that calls the package and it works.